# Change names within a text file

Tags: windows-10, shell-script, powershell-5.0

I have mixed music projects, where the software generates a txt file list of the songs in each project. The problem is that the list is generated with only the first 36 characters of the **name** of each song.

I need to correct the names inside the txt file, so that they are the same as the names of the original files and my script can copy the files using the list.

I created a script, in two blocks, where in the first block I read the original files and generate a variable with the same name as the name inside the txt file.

`First block (what I managed to do):`
Read the original files, in the Original Musics folder, and create the variable with the same name as the one inside the List.txt file.

`Goal of the first block (what I couldn't do):`
When the name in the variable in this block is the same as the name inside List.txt, the script will change the name inside List.txt to the full name of the original file to which the variable is related. Thus, the List.txt file can be read in the second block with the correct names inside it.

Note:
It may happen that there are two files with the same name in the Original Musics folder, but with different versions, in this situation, the two full names of these files must be in the List.txt file to be copied to the destination folder. eg.

Name in List.txt file:
`Got To Be Real (CM_Gex Bootleg Exten`

Original name (full name in the Original Musics folder):

```
Cheryl Lynn - Got To Be Real (CM_Gex Bootleg Extended SHORT Re Mix).mp3
Cheryl Lynn - Got To Be Real (CM_Gex Bootleg Extended LONG Re Mix).mp3
```

Variable $ShortOriginalSongName:

```
Got To Be Real (CM_Gex Bootleg Exten
Got To Be Real (CM_Gex Bootleg Exten
```

As it is the same file, the difference is that one is the long version and the other is the short version, both full names must be in the List.txt file, that is, in addition to changing the names in the list.txt, when the files are the same, the script must include the original full names in the List.txt

Script:

```
$files = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt"
$location = "G:\Original Musics\"
$destination = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Copy Selected Musics\"


# First block:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $location* -Include *.mp3 | % {
    $ShortOriginalSongName = $_.Basename.Split("-")[1].Trim();
    If ($ShortOriginalSongName.Length -gt 36) {$ShortOriginalSongName = $ShortOriginalSongName.Substring(0, 36)};
    };

# Second Block:
Get-Content $files | % {

  $result = gci -recurse "$location*$_" -Include *.mp3
  
  If($result) { 
    Add-Content $destination"AddList.txt" -Value $result.Fullname
    $musicName = $result.Name    
    $tot+=1       
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$musicName found on $location!"
    Write-Host "$musicName copied to $destination..."
    Copy-Item $result.FullName -Destination $destination\$($_.Name)
  } 
}
```

`Second Block:`
Read the List.txt file that was generated with the correct names of the songs in the first block, and copy the original files to the Copy Selected Musics folder.

Comment: Sample filename format would help --- `$_.BaseName.Split('-')[1]` is unexplained,

Comment: @Keith Miller I edited my question and added more information, the information you requested is on the line below `original name (full name in the Original Musics folder):`

Comment: Bonus points for your selection of sample data -- had to pull up "Star Love" on YouTube and indulge in a moment of nostalgia!  :D

Comment: I'm going to compose an answer with suggested modifications to your code. Question: ***Do any of the filenames have characters with special meaning to **PowerShell** strings,  such as square brackets ( `[` or `]`  ) , dollar sign (  `$`  )? If so, some file ops may require the `-LiteralPath` parameter...

Comment: I'll add that if a song name has a dash, the existing split[1] would fail. Another way to do it is `$ShortOriginalSongName = -join (($_.Basename.Split("-")|select -Skip 1).Trim().toCharArray() | select -first 36)`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Using your command when the original name is `Cheryl Lynn - Got To Be Real (Dj 'S' Bootleg Extended Dance Re Mix).mp3` worked, however if the song has more than one dash, eg. `03 - Cheryl Lynn - Got To Be Real (Dj 'S' Bootleg Extended Dance Re Mix).mp3` the dashes are eliminated correctly, but the command `joins the Artist Name with the Song Name`, counts 36 characters and the result is: `Cheryl LynnGot To Be Real (Dj 'S' Bo`, note that the Artist Name is together with the Song Name, so the command `takes everything as the song name` and counts the 36 characters!

Comment: @Clamarc ah, whoops - I think your solution below about removing the additional dashes in song names will help, and then you should use `| select -last 1` instead of either `|select -skip 1` or `[1]`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale OK Cpt, I'll make the changes to the names of my songs, otherwise the script will be too complicated to control this!. I really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of repeated calls to `Get-ChildItem` for `$Location`, so I suggest creating a hashtable that associates short names with their associated files.

You want to:

1. Round up your files:

   ```
   gci $Location *.mp3 -File -Recurse
   ```
2. create a custom object consisting of the calculated short name and the source FileInfo object:

   ```
   [PSCustomObject]@{
       'ShortName' = $_.BaseName.Split('-')[-1].TrimStart().PadRIght(36).Substring(0, 36).TrimEnd()
       'FileInfo'  = $_
   }
   ```
3. Group those by short name ( since multiple files can produce the same short name).

So we start with this:

```
$files       = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt"
$location    = "G:\Original Musics\"
$destination = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Copy Selected Musics\"


$ShortNameList = gci $Location *.mp3 -File -Recurse | %{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ShortName' = $_.BaseName.Split('-')[-1].TrimStart().PadRight(36).Substring(0, 36).TrimEnd()
        'FileInfo'  = $_
}} | Group ShortName
```

Then convert that object to a hashtable:

```
$ShortNameLookup = $ShortNameList | ForEach { $hash = @{} } {
    $hash.Add($_.Name , @( $_.Group.FileInfo ))
} { $hash }
```

Then the core processing uses each entry in `$files` as the hash key:

```
Get-Content $files | %{
    If ( $FileInfo = $ShortNameLookup[$_] ) {
        Add-Content ( Join-Path $Destination 'AddList.txt' ) $FileInfo.FullName
        $FileInfo | %{
            Write-Host ( '"{0}" found in "{1}"' -f $_.BaseName , $_.DirectoryName)
        }
        $FileInfo | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
    }
    Else { Write-Host "No files found that match '$_'." }
}
```

Untested, but pretty sure the logic is sound. Wanted to get the code up -- will add notes later this evening.

Comment: Error `Exception when calling "Add" with "2" argument(s):` Key cannot be null. `$hash.Add($_.ShortName , @( $_.Group.FileInfo ))` Maybe this error occurs because the name in List.txt has a `maximum` of 36 characters, but 19, 6, 16 characters can occur. Notice in my script the `If ($ShortOriginalSongName.Length -gt 36)` to only set the $musicNameRight if that length is greater than 36. I noticed now is that in the original folder, files which contain more than one `-`, eg. `03 - Cheryl Lynn - Got To Be Real` so the `ShortName` must be made from the last `-`.

Comment: The multiple hyphen issue is easy enough to solve. If you always want the content to the right of the *final* hyphen in the basename, we just change the index into the `.Split()` result to `[-1]` -- I'll edit that.

Comment: OK, the `$hash.Add()` error was due to the fact that since I had grouped on ShortName, that was now the `Name` property of the GroupInfo object, That is now fixed.

Comment: I was in a hurry earlier, and hadn't even added the `.SubString()` to the code. I avoided the length test and branching by using `.PadRigth(36)` before `.SubString(0,36)` and split the trimming into two parts so leading spaces are removed before the substring is created. Should be good now or quite close.

Comment: OK, I'll test the code... just one more question: what if the name of the original song contains some traction, eg. `Cheryl Lynn - Got To Be Real (CM_Gex Bootleg Extended - SHORT Re Mix)` note that `after Extended has a dash` how will the ShortName command handle this?

Comment: The `$ShortName` calculated for that filename would be `Short Remix)`, so it wouldn't match the song title in your text file. If all/most of your .mp3s have metadata that includes the `Title` field, querying that would be a more reliable way to obtain the song title (assuming the field was populated correctly), though it would increase processing time, as the actual file has to be accessed, rather than just directory info.

Comment: OK Keith, I asked about this so that I can manually organize the names of my Songs, that is, the Songs that have a dash in the Name, I will remove the dash one by one so that the script works correctly, ok? ... later I will test the last changes you made to the code, I haven't had time to do it calmly yet.

Comment: You can use Explorer search to find filenames with multiple hyphens. In the Explorer search bar, use `name:~"*-*-*-*"` to find filenames with three or more hyphens.  `"*-*-*-*-*"` will find names with at least four -- so work your way down from most to least.

Comment: OK Keith, your last changes worked!... I just had to change a syntax error in the second Write-Host command, it's like `Wirte-Host`. The song I used as a sample is part of a collection I have with the best Black Music from the 70's and 80's. Here, at my house, they are always on my party playlist!... I really appreciate your help, thank you boy .

Comment: a question with the test I did. I have a song named `Front 242 - Headhunter_Original_Mix.mp3`, the script is considering the sign "_" as if it were the sign "-"... in this situation, I'll also have to change my songs with the sign `_ `, is that it?

Comment: forget my question... the problem was an extra white space in the song name... which was causing the names to not match when looking for the file, ok? sorry my mistake!

Comment: Just a note: sometimes the script shows the message `Add-Content Process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\AddList.txt' because it is being used by another process.` so I changed it the command `Add-Content ( Join-Path $Destination 'AddList.txt' ) $FileInfo.FullName` to `$FileInfo.FullName | Out-File ( Join-Path $Destination 'AddList.txt' ) -Append` and so far the message has not appeared anymore, ok?